# Pandas keyerror for concatenated string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, concatenation

```
df_test = df[0].head(4)
count_array = ' \'Page_count_0\''
count_array = '[\'Index_0\', \'VAstart\','  + count_array + ']'
print('{}'.format(count_array))
df_test['{}'.format(count_array)]
```

KeyError: "['Index_0', 'VAstart', 'Page_count_0']"

For completeness, I was trying to print following columns from a huge dataframe

Index_0 VAstart Count_0 Count_1 Count_2 Count_3 Count_4 Count_5

Comment: When I cut and paste the string (count_array) it works. Dataframe is parsing the concatenated string as one key instead of multiple keys

Comment: remove the square brackets from the string? what are you trying to do, select multile columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have defined it, count_array contains a single string:

```
"['Index_0', 'VAstart', 'Page_count_0']"
```

Unless I have misunderstood (as you haven't included any information about the dataframe) you're just trying to access a dataframe selecting a list of keys. If that's the case, could define `count_array` as

```
count_array = 'Page_count_0'
count_array = ['Index_0', 'VAstart', count_array]
```

That way `count_array` is a list of keys, and not just one long string:

```
['Index_0', 'VAstart', 'Page_count_0']
```

And you can access `df_test[count_array]` directly

Comment: This works. My dataframe has Page_count_0, Page_count_1 and so on. It is a variable based on number of log files I have. thanks.